# How can i change keyboard language while changing the text field in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface, keyboard

i want to change the language of the keyboard automatically when change the focus from one text field to another how can i do it?

Lets say i have towo fields one is for english language input and other is arabic language so when changing focus from english to arabic field i want the automatic change in the keyboard layout so that i can enter the specific field in the respective language.

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Regards:
Majid Hussain

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard languages are not tied to system language and different manufacturers uses different keyboard apps (like gboard, swift key etc)

You can do one thing is that accept only specific language in text field

For English:

```
TextField(
 inputFormatters: [
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]'))
 ],
)
```

For Arabic:

```
TextField(
 inputFormatters: [
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[\u0600-\u06FF]'))
 ],
)
```

Regular expression \u0600-\u06FF matches all Unicode characters in the range of Arabic characters